# Using boto (AWS Python), how do I get a list of IAM users?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam

Newbie question. I'm expecting to be able to do something like the following:

```
import boto
from boto.iam.connection import IAMConnection
cfn = IAMConnection()
cfn.get_all_users()
for user in userList:
    print user.user_id
```

The connection works fine, but the last line returns the error "'unicode' object has no attribute 'user_id'".

I did a `type(userList)` and it reported the type as <class 'boto.jsonresponse.Element'>, which doesn't appear (?) to be documented. Using normal JSON parsing doesn't appear to work either.

From [another source](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.boto/1804/match=jsonresponse), it looks as if the intent is the results of an operation like this are supposed to be "pythonized."

Anyway, I'm pretty new to boto, so I assume there's some simple way to do this that I just haven't stumbled across.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some of the older AWS services, boto takes the XML responses from the service and turns them into nice Python objects.  For others, it takes the XML response and transliterates it directly into native Python data structures.  The `boto.iam` module is of the latter form.  So, the actual data returned by `get_all_users()` looks like this:

```
{u'list_users_response':
  {u'response_metadata': {u'request_id': u'8d694cbd-93ec-11e3-8276-993b3edf6dba'},   
   u'list_users_result': {u'users': 
     [{u'path': u'/', u'create_date': u'2014-01-21T17:19:45Z', u'user_id': 
       u'<userid>', u'arn': u'<arn>', u'user_name': u'foo'},
      {...next user...}
     ]
  }
}
```

So, all of the data you want is there, it's just a bit difficult to find.  The `boto.jsonresponse.Element` object returned does give you a little help.  You can actually do something like this:

```
data = cfn.get_all_users()
for user in data.user:
    print(user['user_name'])
```

but for the most part you just have to dig around in the data returned to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is what ended up working for me:

`    data = cfn.get_all_users()  
    for user in data.list_users_result.users:  
        print(user.user_name)`

Comment: I give up on trying to format code in the comments for now, arg. Suffice to say that I needed to iterate over `data.list_usres_result.users`, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: One of the nice things that is coming in boto3 is a uniform object layer on top of all of the services so you don't have to muck around in the low-level data structures.

Comment: Nice! Looking forward to it.